# How to do multi-way joins in XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Given this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<r> 
  <Rk> 
    <Req>111</Req>  
    <RkNumber>123456</RkNumber>  
    <RkName>John</RkName> 
  </Rk>  
  <Rk> 
    <Req>111</Req>  
    <RkNumber>9876</RkNumber>  
    <RkName>Joe</RkName> 
  </Rk>  
  <Covg> 
    <Req>111</Req>  
    <RkNumber>123456</RkNumber>  
    <CvgNumber>123</CvgNumber> 
  </Covg>  
  <Covg> 
    <Req>111</Req>  
    <RkNumber>9876</RkNumber>  
    <CvgNumber>321</CvgNumber> 
  </Covg>  
  <Comp> 
    <Req>111</Req>  
    <CvgNumber>123</CvgNumber>  
    <CompTyp>ABC</CompTyp> 
  </Comp>  
  <Comp> 
    <Req>111</Req>  
    <CvgNumber>321</CvgNumber>  
    <CompTyp>DEF</CompTyp> 
  </Comp> 
</r>
```

I want to select the `RkName` where the `CompTyp` = 'ABC'.
I tried this XPath,

```
//Rk[RkNumber = //Covg/RkNumber and //Covg/CvgNumber = //Comp/CvgNumber and //Comp[CompTyp = 'ABC']]/RkName
```

but it returns "John" and "Joe".  I would only expect to have "John" returned.

Answer (score 1):

Use this XPath,

```
//Rk[RkNumber=//Covg[CvgNumber=//Comp[CompTyp='ABC']/CvgNumber]/RkNumber]/RkName
```

to select the `RkName` associated with the `Covg` via `RkNumber` which in turn is associated with a `Comp` via `CvgNumber` for the `Comp` with a`CompTyp` of `ABC`,

```
<RkName>John</RkName>
```

as requested.

Comment: But note that with many XPath processors, this is going to have O(n^3) performance - that is, if it takes 1ms for a 1Kb document then it will take 10^6 seconds (about 11.6 days) for a 1Mb document and about 33 years for a 10Mb document.

Comment: Right, try to restrict @MichaelKay's `n` to be less than the number of elements in the document via predicates or subtree selections such as `/r/X` rather than `//X`.